# PDFBox I need to wrap the link tags with reference tag

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, tagged-pdf

I need to wrap the `link` tags with the `reference` tag.

```
private static PDStructureElement wrapInElement(String structType, PDStructureElement pdStructureElement) {
    PDStructureNode parentNode = pdStructureElement.getParent();
    PDStructureElement structureElement = null;
    if (parentNode!=null && parentNode instanceof PDStructureElement)  {
        structureElement = new PDStructureElement(structType,parentNode);
        structureElement.setElementIdentifier("wrap"+noteID++);
        parentNode.insertBefore(structureElement,pdStructureElement);
        structureElement.setParent(parentNode);
        structureElement.appendKid(pdStructureElement);
        parentNode.removeKid(pdStructureElement);
    }
    return structureElement;
}
```

And it does the structural changes. But in PAC3 it shows below error,

> "Link" annotation is not nested inside a "Link" structure element

Please help me to solve the problem. [Sample PDF here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wvBJVdTy4ZNe7RuYEQ892poPZxCntcZA/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> parentNode.removeKid(pdStructureElement);

Should be done before "appendkid".

```
private static PDStructureElement wrapInElement(String structType, PDStructureElement pdStructureElement) {
            PDStructureNode parentNode = pdStructureElement.getParent();
            PDStructureElement structureElement = null;
            if (parentNode!=null && parentNode instanceof PDStructureElement)  {
                structureElement = new PDStructureElement(structType,parentNode);
                parentNode.insertBefore(structureElement,pdStructureElement);
                structureElement.setParent(parentNode);
                parentNode.removeKid(pdStructureElement);
                structureElement.appendKid(pdStructureElement);
            }
            return structureElement;
        }
```